# Failed to sync github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-desktop

I'm tring to syncronize my branch with master but github give me an error:

[image]

I use github desktop app.Anyone can help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Open a shell and add the output of the following commands: `git status` and  `git pull`.

Comment: +1 I get this same issue with absolutely no repo problems in power shell. It fails to sync even if everything is fine and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

```
1.git checkout master
2.git pull origin master
3.git checkout [your branch]
4.git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use C:\xampp\htdocs\tsm_r20 [master ≡]>git status.
>
> then C:\xampp\htdocs\tsm_r20 [master ≡]>git push.

Open "git shell" set your repository path use git status command based on that you can proceed or use git push command.